# Java 8 - limiting stream of first object and convert to specific object?

Tags: java, list, java-8, java-stream

Earlier I use:

```
List<Person> person = UserDB.getUserDetails();
Person p = person.get(0); // index of first position 
System.out.println(p.getFirstName()); // sometime i am getting 
                                      // NULL pointer issue if person object is null
```

in Java 8, I tried with `map(Person::new)`. it is causing the issue.

```
person.stream().limit(1).map(Person::new).
```

How can I implement?

Comment: Why use a stream for that? Should be `.map(Person::getFirstName).forEach(System.out::println)`

Comment: So, what is your problem? That `UserDB.getUserDetails()` is returning null emelents inside the list?

Comment: You can use `Optional` methods to return an empty `Person` if the first `Person` in the `List` is `null` - assuming that's what you're trying to do. Not particularly clear from context.

Comment: I need to take first person object from list for further process. here i am just printing.

Comment: Why are `null` objects being put into the list in the first place? What does that mean? Maybe it shouldn't be.

Comment: I couldn't take first index position object using stream

Comment: I am taking + ve scenario.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
person.stream()                                              // stream
      .findFirst()                                           // finds the first
      .ifPresent(i -> System.out.println(i.getFirstName())); // if present, print the name
```

If you want to work with the `Person` in case the `List<Person>` is empty, use [`Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html):

```
Optional<Person> p = person.stream().findFirst();
p.ifPresent(i -> System.out.println(i.getFirstName()));
```

This solution assumes the list has elements or not (is empty). However if `null` occurs in the `List<Person>`, you have to filter the `null` values out first:

```
Optional<Person> p = person.stream().filter(Objects::nonNull).findFirst();
p.ifPresent(i -> System.out.println(i.getFirstName()));
```

Finally, if you wish to work with a `Person` on the specific index, use `skip` and `limit`. Don't forget to filter the `List<Person>` *after* skip-limit` or else the index will not match:

```
// person.get(3)
Optional<Person> p = person.stream().skip(3).limit(1).filter(Objects::nonNull).findFirst();
p.ifPresent(i -> System.out.println(i.getName()));
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Optional<Person> firstName = 
   person.stream()
         .limit(1)
         .filter(Objects::notNull)
         .findFirst();
```

You are better returning an `Optional<Person>` if your first element is null, thus forcing whoever is using this to take proper actions.

Or even simpler:

```
Optional<Person> first = Optional.ofNullable(person.get(0));
```

Comment: @Thanks Eugene for your solution

Comment: @Eugene: The second "simpler" way will throw `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0` in case the `List<Person> person` has no element (is empty).

Comment: @Nikolas of course, but that is not a concern from the OP's question

Comment: Note also that using functional style here is overkill and OP would be better off sticking to the original imperative code with an added null-check.

Comment: @Eugene: As far as the OP is a begginer, he does not know it should be his/her concern. It's a good way to warn him at least.

Answer (score 0):

How about this, it will handle null scenario too;

```
System.out.println(Optional
                .ofNullable(UserDB.getUserDetails())
                .orElse(Collections.emptyList())
                .stream()
                .map(Person::getName)
                .findFirst()
                .orElse(null));
```